# ggplot geosmooth legends R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show shaded Confidence Intervals of 95% and 68% for a linear model. Also, I want to show respective legends of x1,95% CI and 68% CI. But instead, I am getting a range of intervals.

Here is my data

```
YEAR  2004 2005 2006 2007 2008  
x1    -0.1   -1.8   -1.3   -1  -1.3
```

Code so far:

```
library(ggplot2)

data=read.csv(file.choose())

s1=ggplot(data,aes (x = YEAR, y = x1)) 

p <-
s1+                                                                                     
  geom_smooth(method="lm",color="black",aes(alpha=0.05),show.legend=TRUE)+  
  geom_smooth(method="lm",color="black",aes(alpha=0.32),show.legend=TRUE)+                                 
  scale_color_discrete(name='')+
  geom_point(size=5.5)+
  geom_line(linetype="dotted",size=2)+       
  xlab("Year")+                                                                         
  ylab("x1")+
  guides(alpha = guide_legend(nrow = 16))+
  annotate("text", x = 2007.4, y = 2, label = "Test",face="bold",size=16)+              
  geom_hline(linetype="dashed",aes(yintercept=0))
p
```

And what I get is this:
[image: And what I get is this:]

Comment: Please, please read the help text: "**`level`**: level of confidence interval to use (0.95 by default)."

Answer (score 1):

## Example data

```
data <- data.frame(YEAR = 2004:2008,
                   x1 = c(0, -2, -1.5, -1, -1.5))
```

## Make a plot

- We use `level` to indicate the confidence interval.
- We can use `fill` inside `aes` to indicate we want to make a legend for the level.
- I stayed with your black and white.
- I got rid of some clutter code.
- `yintercept = 0` should be outside `aes`, since it is a static value.

Plotting code:

```
ggplot(data,aes (x = YEAR, y = x1)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(fill = "68%"), level = 0.68, col = 1) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(fill = "95%"), level = 0.95, col = 1) +
  geom_point(size = 5.5) +
  geom_line(linetype = "dotted", size = 2) +
  geom_hline(linetype = "dashed", yintercept = 0) +
  xlab("Year") +
  scale_fill_grey(name = 'Confidence\n level') +
  theme_classic()
```

## Result

[image]